# Memory leak in SmithDecomposition?

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra, memory

While trying to compute a large number of Smith decompositions in Mathematica 11.0 under Windows 10, my computer keeps running out of memory for no apparent reason.

Here is a self-contained example illustrating the problem.

Define a 176-by-386 matrix `A` as follows (it seems that the matrix has to be sufficiently complicated for the problems to arise):

```
entry[i_, j_] := If[Length[Complement[j, i]] == 1, (-1)^Position[j, Complement[j, i][[1]]][[1,1]], 0]
A = Table[entry[i, j], {i, Subsets[Range[10], 3]}, {j, Subsets[Range[10], 4]}];
```

Now, we try to compute the `SmithDecomposition` of this matrix 10000 times in a row. We are not displaying any output or storing the result anywhere and the matrix we are computing with is fixed:

```
For[k = 1, k <= 10000, k++, SmithDecomposition[A];]
```

Despite this, each iteration of the `For` loop seems to be eating more and more memory and I can find no way to clear this memory up between iterations. (I tried using `ClearSystemCache`, setting `$HistoryLength = 1`, etc. as suggested in the answers to some related questions, but nothing seems to work.) The memory does not clear up after aborting the computation either.

> What is eating up all my memory and how do I clear it up between successive computations?

**Added:** As noted by Henrik Schumacher in the comment, this problem does not seem to be present in Mathematica 11.3. I am still curious how to clear up memory after a leak of this kind. (When working on a computer that only has an earlier version of Mathematica available, this kind of error can be detrimental to work progress, so it would be nice to have a workaround.)

> Is killing the kernel the only way or are there less drastic solutions?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with version 11.3 on macOS. But that does not mean much since such issues can easily OS-dependent.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: I installed version 11.3 now and I cannot reproduce the problem in that version either. Must be a bug that they removed between these versions.

Comment: That's good to hear, Dejan!

Comment: @DejanGovc What version of Mathematica were you seeing the leak?

Comment: @ChipHurst: 11.0.1.0.